# Create a new column in a CSV file based on the values of 2 other columns

Tags: ubuntu, awk, csv

I have a csv with 23 columns containing data from a network scan. I need to create a new column based on the data from the last 2 columns (22 and 23). My desired output is as follows:

New column heading = Labelled

```
if column 22 = Malicious and column 23= C&C-FileDownload then new column 24= 1
```

Can someone help me achieve this using Ubuntu? I've been looking into this and I can see awk is the tool to use but I'm very new to this.

So far I've tried this: `awk 'NR==1{$24="merge";print;next} \ $22 == "Malicious" || $23 == "C&C-FileDownload" {$24=1}1' Malware-44-1.csv > test1.csv` but it doesn't add the new columns with "1", it does add "Merged" as a column but doesn't comma delimit it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell that to awk what is the input field seperator. With `-F,` we are telling it's a comma character. You also need to tell that what is the output field seperator. With `-v OFS=,` we specified that is also should be a comma character.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{ $24="merge"; print; next }
{ $24=($22 == "Malicious" && $23 == "C&C-FileDownload") }1
' Malware-44-1.csv > output.csv
```

I have also updated the commnad so that column#24 would be 0 if conditions didn't met otherwise 1 if it was true, so all the records will have the same number of columns;

In case you wanted to left those column empty rather than filling with 0, then:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{ $24="merge"; print; next }
{ $24=($22 == "Malicious" && $23 == "C&C-FileDownload"?1:"") }1
' Malware-44-1.csv > output.csv
```

to define multiple rules, do:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{ $24="merge"; print; next }
($22 == "Malicious" && $23 == "C&C-FileDownload") { $24=1 }
( .... ) { $24=2 }
( .... ) { $24=3 }
( .... ) { # and some more ... }
1' Malware-44-1.csv > output.csv
```

or to skip processing the later conditions if one met the condition, do:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'NR==1{ $24="merge"; print; next }
($22 == "Malicious" && $23 == "C&C-FileDownload") { $24=1; print; next }
( .... ) { $24=2; print; next }
( .... ) { $24=3; print; next }
( .... ) { # and some more ... }
' Malware-44-1.csv > output.csv
```

---

Or you can also print that separately after printing the current record:

```
awk 'NR==1{ print $0 ",merge" }
NR>1{ print $0 "," ($22 == "Malicious" && $23 == "C&C-FileDownload"?1:"") }
' Malware-44-1.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your `awk` code:

1. There is no input field separator defined.  If the input is a simple CSV file (meaning there are no fields with embedded commas, quotes, or newlines), then you will probably want to set the variable `FS` to a comma (e.g. by using `-F ,` on the command line).  If you don't set `FS`, `awk` will use any run of consecutive whitespace characters as the input field separator.
2. There is no output field separator defined.  As soon as you modify or add a field, the whole record will be output with the value of `OFS` as the field delimiter.  This is, by default, a single space, but it should probably be a comma character in this instance.
3. The logic that you described is different from what you implemented.  You said fields 22 and 23 should be particular values, but you implemented *or*.

Instead:

```bash
awk -F , '
    BEGIN { OFS = FS }
    NR == 1 { $24 = "Merge" }
    $22 == "Malicious" && $23 == "C&C-FileDownload" { $24 = 1 }
    NF != 24 { $24 = "" } # add empty field at end to make 24 fields
    { print }' file
```

If your data is a CSV file with embedded commas, quotes, and newlines, then you probably should be using a CSV-aware tool to at least do the initial parsing of the data, as well as the final output of it, to represent all fields correctly.